# How can I make ZFS datasets mount automatically on boot?

Tags: mount, systemd, 19.10, zfs

I use ZFS to store my data, including configuration files, for my desktop PC, so it's important for my datasets to mount automatically on boot. I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to do this in Ubuntu 19.10.

At first, when I ran `zfs list` and `zpool list`, there was no output; it was empty. Then, after figuring out how to import my pools, they still wouldn't mount.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this is to make sure three unit files are `enable`d to start on boot:

- `zfs.target`, which is the overarching target for all of ZFS
- `zfs-import.service`, which imports zpools at boot
- `zfs-mount.service`, which mounts all datasets at boot

These units have dependencies set up correctly, so you can simply run:

`systemctl enable zfs.target zfs-import.service zfs-mount.service`

to ensure they are all turned on. After this, reboot to test; your ZFS datasets should show up.

Comment: This worked for me on 18.04 as well, despite `zfs.target` not being found (as outlined in more detail [in this question about how the selection of datasets-to-mount works internally](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259269/how-to-automount-specific-zfs-dataset-at-boot)). If you happen to know more and could provide an answer to my question, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that zfs-zed.service which updates zpool cache and zfs-list cache to no longer be running after a systemctl suspend and require manual restart, if I forget that the caches don't get updated for any later changes for next reboot.
I'll improve this with details shortly to replicate and try a clean install on the weekend and or move this to the to the proper place. Openzfs 2.1.5 with compatibility set to openzfs-2.1-linux. Ubuntu 22.04 and proxmox hacked with zsys sharing  boot and root pools.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1267218)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Personally, I find it a bit frustrating that people are told to comment when they aren't able to do so.