# How to automount specific zfs dataset at boot?

Tags: boot, 18.04, mount, automount, zfs

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with encrypted ZFS on `/` and have now decided that I would like to make my `/home` directory a separate dataset.

#### Initial Issue

As per [Proper way to create a zfs off an existing directory?](https://serverfault.com/a/629889/241793) I created a new dataset with mount point at `/home`.

```
# backup data
sudo mv /home /home-backup
# create empty dataset
sudo zfs create tank/ds1/home # you could already specify the mountpoint here.
# oops, I forgot to set the mountpoint so it is now /tank/ds1/home
sudo zfs set mountpoint=/home tank/ds1/home
# copy data to newly created dataset
sudo rsync -aAX /home-backup/ /home
```

After reboot I cannot login in the GUI anymore - entering the correct password just throws me back to the login screen. But that's not a big problem: In the Terminal that opens when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> I can login and run `sudo zfs mount tank/ds1/home` and after that, logging in in the GUI works fine. The problem is just that this dataset is not automatically mounted at boot.

Some advice in the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ZFS#Using_zfs-mount.service) advises to use certain services, but I don't know if that also applies to my ubuntu and also I would like to only automount `tank/ds1/home` (mountpoint `/home`) and `tank/ds1/u18` (mountpoint `/`, is already automounted  somehow) but not `tank/ds1` (which only exists for hierarchical purposes) if that can be avoided.

#### Questions

- **How can I automount my home directory dataset at boot?**
  "Solved". See the section Solution below.
- **Why is my root directory dataset automatically mounted at boot?**
  I'm happy that it is, but I am curious why. If it is within the scope of the first question, please answer this too.
- **Which datasets get auto-mounted by the zfs mount service?**
  The basis for this question is outlined in the section Remaining Question) below.

#### System Information

```bash
$ uname -a
Linux motorbrot 5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:07:03 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ zfs version
zfs-0.8.4-1
zfs-kmod-0.8.4-1
```

Listing the zfs datasets right after booting (before temporarily fixing anything) shows the datasets and their mountpoints and they are as expected. Using `zfs get all tank/ds1/home | grep mount` and similar commands shows that all are `canmount on` but only `tank/ds1/u18` is mounted (on `/`).

My `/etc/fstab` contains only my swap partition and my EXT2 `/boot` partition.

My `/etc/default/zfs` contains `ZFS_MOUNT='yes'` but that seems to have no effect, since not all datasets are being mounted. That can perhaps be explained by the comment `Changing some of these settings may not make any difference on systemd-based setup, e.g. setting ZFS_MOUNT=no will not prevent systemd from launching zfs-mount.service during boot.`.

```bash
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep zfs
zfs-import.service         generated
zfs-mount.service          generated
zfs-share.service          generated
zfs-zed.service            masked
```

#### Solution

Following [How can I make ZFS datasets mount automatically on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186283/how-can-i-make-zfs-datasets-mount-automatically-on-boot) I am informed that `zfs.target` does not exist and that both `zfs-import.service` and `zfs-mount.service` are "not native services, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install".
[image]
After running these commands, the output of `systemctl list-unit-files | grep zfs` is still the same. I would have expected the status to change to `enabled`.

However, after a reboot the login works again - `/tank/ds1/home` is mounted correctly to `/home`.

Now that I am finding this question again, a year later, having the exact same problem with a new encrypted dataset, this "solution" is not helping anymore.

#### Remaining Question

The outputs of `zfs get all DATASET | grep mount` show that `tank` and `tank/ds1` are not mounted after boot while `tank/ds1/u18` and `tank/ds1/home` are mounted on their respective mountpoints. That's great! **But why are only those two automatically mounted?** It's exactly as it should be, but I fail to see why it is behaving that way.

So what I am asking in the end is: Please explain to me how ubuntu decides which zfs datasets are automatically mounted during boot. How could I specify specific datasets to be automatically mounted?

**How can I automount a specific encrypted dataset at boot?**

(Edit 2023): My current suspicion is that the datasets are generally automounted unless the specified mountpoint is not an empty directory. I.e. because I have other directories inside the directory `/tank/ds1`, it will not automount `tank/ds1` there.

Comment: @user68186 it's not an answer. It's an adjacent magical side effect that I am asking for an explanation for. It may be useful for answering, it may be useful for visitors with the same issues, but it is definitely not an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to use this method for storing your home directory, but be that as it may, since you can get the desired result after running commands you might consider https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up